# ng command not found everytime i logged to GCP Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, angular-cli, google-cloud-shell

I noticed everytime i login Google Cloud Shell, my 'ng' command is not recognized

```
weilies@cloudshell:~/dev (cloud-xp)$ cd sunny-app/
weilies@cloudshell:~/dev/sunny-app (cloud-xp)$ ng serve -disable-host-check
-bash: ng: command not found
```

I have to reinstall them with command then i got back my ng command.
weilies@cloudshell:~ (cloud-xp)$ ng --version

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.7
Node: 10.14.2
OS: linux x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.7
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.7
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.7
@schematics/angular          9.1.7
@schematics/update           0.901.7
rxjs                         6.5.4
```

But one thing i noticed, the installation return with error (but it doesn't stop me running my angular app, so i simply ignored)

```
weilies@cloudshell:~ (cloud-xp)$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v10.14.2/bin/ng -> /usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v10.14.2/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@9.1.7 postinstall /usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v10.14.2/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@9.1.7
added 271 packages from 206 contributors in 15.296s
```

It is just annoying i need to install angular/cli everytime i login GCP Clould shell. Isn't ng installed globally with a -g flag?

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the fact that, when you run `npm install -g @angular/cli`, it is installed globally (in the `/usr/local/` directory).

Cloud Shell, however, has some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations), one of them being that it is a "volatile" instance and any modifications that you made to it outside your `$HOME` are lost after the session is terminated.

Cloud Shell is meant for quick testing or administrative commands. You may rather use a Compute Engine instance (you can have 1 [F1-micro instance for free](https://cloud.google.com/free)) for development needs.

Comment: i had claimed the free instance. reason i need "ng" because i gonna do some "serious" development in GCP.  I need to cool Editor feature which not available in the instance. so i guess i hv to live with it. Just re-install everytime i visit cloud shell

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Shell VMs are ephemeral and are discarded at the end of each session (your Cloud Shell home directory, however, is persistent).  However, it is possible to add a script to customize the Cloud Shell environment on startup.  Please follow the [directions in Cloud Shell documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#environment_customization).